# Can not compile anything by fp (Free Pascal IDE) and there is no help

Tags: 20.04, configuration, ide, free, pascal

If I try to compile a simple program by `fp` that is a Free Pascal integrated development environment installed along with `fpc` package, I get error "Fatal: Can't find unit system"..
I can compile the program by `fpc` command line compiler, but "The IDE has an internal compiler."

I also wonder, if I have to add help files one by one in Help > Files... by browsing to the source directory where I extracted them in each time I run `fp` in a new directory?

Answer (score 1):

- How to use `Free Pascal` (`Lazarus`) on `Linux` (`Ubuntu`) - *no install* solution:

1. If not already installed, install "GNU binutils" (`sudo apt-get install binutils`)
2. Dowload the latest version of `Free Pascal` (`Lazarus`) `.deb` package ("`fpc-laz_ ... .deb`") from the [Downloads](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads) section of the [Lazarus Home page](https://www.lazarus-ide.org) (*Lazarus* is a professional open-source cross platform IDE powered by *Free Pascal*):
3. Place the downloaded `.deb` package in the folder where you are going to extract it
4. Extract the downloaded `.deb` package by *Right-Click*-ing it and then choosing *Extract Here*:
5. Rename the extracted folder, as you desire, for example "*fpc*"; Further we denote the extracted folder as "`<BASEPATH>`"
6. Open the extracted folder and then, extract "`data.tar.xz`" - as "*data*" folder
7. Launch the `Free Pascal` window by typing the next command in the terminal (this command may vary according to the terminal used - in this case (`Ubuntu`) it is used `gnome-terminal`):

   `gnome-terminal -e '<BASEPATH>/data/usr/bin/fp'`

   OR:

   `gnome-terminal -- '<BASEPATH>/data/usr/bin/fp'`
8. To add units folders: From the `Free Pascal` Menu, access: `Options` -> `Directories` -> and drag and drop to the "`Units`" tab, the next three lines, line by line (each on a new line):

   `<BASEPATH>/data/usr/lib/fpc/$fpcversion\units\$fpctarget`

   `<BASEPATH>/data/usr/lib/fpc/$fpcversion\units\$fpctarget\*`

   `<BASEPATH>/data/usr/lib/fpc/$fpcversion\units\$fpctarget\rtl`

   Please note that by moving the files from the `<BASEPATH>` directory to other "`<BASEPATH>`", you'll have to update the above three lines so that they contain the new `<BASEPATH>`, otherwise you might get errors like:

   "`Fatal: Can't find unit ...`"
9. For Official *Installation* and *Online Documentation* see:

   [Installation](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Installing_the_Free_Pascal_Compiler)

   [Online Documentation](https://www.freepascal.org/docs.html)

- Regarding adding help files one by one using: `Help` -> `Files` -> `New`:

  - if the help files are located in a folder that is not moved - for example outside the `<BASEPATH>` directory - you won't have to readd the help files;
  - also adding the help files could be done by editing the `[Help]` section ("`Files=...`") in the `fp.ini` file used by the `fp` binary

Comment: Thanks. You can also install the version available in _universe_ repository, which might be older.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved, following this article: https://sebcosta.altervista.org/joomla/articles/37-free-pascal.html (great tutorial from Sebastien Costa!).

My Free Pascal is installed dowloading a .deb file from
https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/fp-ide
on a Linux Mint 19.2 version (tina).